# Should we create a tag for skiing?

Tags: discussion, tagging

We have at least three questions involving bikes and skiing; see the first few [in this search](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=ski+is%3Aquestion). Should we create a ski tag, or perhaps a tag for other outdoor activities?

Also, [this question has a lift tag](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/28644/how-to-board-a-ski-chairlift-that-is-not-intended-for-bicycles), which I don't think we need. Should we remove the tag, or replace it with one relating to transporting bikes?

Comment: skiing sounds like a really narrow category, maybe something to indicate downhill riding though? The tag "downhill" already exists. Alternatively, the "transportation" tag exists also.

Answer (score 4):

I think a tag on transporting bikes is fine (which will almost totally be on car racks). As for a ski tag, I don't think its worth it. The questions are too niche and rare to merit their own tag (note that there's no coherence between the 3 questions which come up -- ski helmets for biking (should be under helmets or something), carrying skis on a bike (luggage/cargo would work for this) or taking a bike up a ski lift (I think thats the only question of the sort this site will see for years)).

The lift tag should also be removed since I don't think anyone will need it.

Answer (score 0):

How about a "biking and" tag with a tag wiki entry along the lines of "Questions about combining biking with another activity – such as how do you carry your dog (or skis) on your bike? Please include the other activity in the subject of your question."

Comment: Too complicated, and too peripheral to the site in most cases. A lot of these questions would likely be better for Outdoors.se or something, or would come up so rarely that it doesn't merit a tag.